# ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have multi-output

```
out = [Dense(19, name='one', activation='softmax')(out),
           Dense(19, name='two', activation='softmax')(out),
           Dense(19, name='three', activation='softmax')(out),
           Dense(19, name='four', activation='softmax')(out)]


model.fit(reshape_train_X,  y_onehot, batch_size=400, epochs=100, verbose=2,
          validation_split=0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

This is my  y_onehot format:

```
[array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
      dtype=uint8), array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],dtype=uint8),.....]
```

And I got this error message

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 5000 arrays: [array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ...
```

I don't know why this error occurs when y_onehot has four lists in the array.

len(y_onehot): 5000

print("y_onehot", y_onehot[0])

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

print("y_onehot", len(y_onehot[0]))

```
y_onehot 4
```

I try [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9475)  . But still didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try passing `y_onehot` to the `model.fit` as `np.array(y_onehot)` ?

Comment: Yes, But still get this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a dummy example. pay attention to your y. you have to pass in fit each output separated

```
inp = Input((50))
x = Dense(32)(inp)
x1 = Dense(19, name='one', activation='softmax')(x)
x2 = Dense(19, name='two', activation='softmax')(x)
x3 = Dense(19, name='three', activation='softmax')(x)
x4 = Dense(19, name='four', activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, [x1,x2,x3,x4])
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (5000,50))
y1 = np.random.randint(0,2, (5000,19))
y2 = np.random.randint(0,2, (5000,19))
y3 = np.random.randint(0,2, (5000,19))
y4 = np.random.randint(0,2, (5000,19))

model.fit(X, [y1,y2,y3,y4], epochs=10)
```

Comment: This work! Pass in fit each output separated is right! Thank you very much.